# Dijkstra - Locate Previous Vector

Tags: java, algorithm, path, dijkstra

This is my sample code for a class Dijkstra:

```
public class Dijkstra {

    public static int[] GetPath(IGraph graph,int start,int end){

    int[] dist=new int[graph.size()+1];
    Stack<Integer> Path =new Stack<Integer>();
    int[] previous=new int[graph.size()+1];
    boolean[] visited=new boolean[graph.size()+1];

    HashSet<Integer> Q=new HashSet<Integer>();

    int i,u = 0,min;

    for (i=0;i<graph.size();i++){
        dist[i]=10000;
        visited[i]=false;
        previous[i]=-1;     
    }
    dist[start]=0;  
    Q.add(start);

    while(!Q.isEmpty()){
        min=1000;   
        for(i=0;i<graph.size();i++){
            if(dist[i]<min&&visited[i]==false){
                min=dist[i];
                u=i;

            }
        }

        Q.remove(u);
        visited[u]=true;

        //Process all the outbound vertexes of the current vertex;
        int[] outb=graph.IterateOutbound(u);
        if(outb!=null){
            for (int v=0;v<outb.length-1;v++){
                int alt=dist[u]+graph.retrieveCost(u, outb[v]);
                if(alt<dist[outb[v]]&&!visited[outb[v]]){
                    dist[outb[v]]=alt;
                    previous[outb[v]]=u;
                    Q.add(outb[v]);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return previous;
    }


}
```

I can't figure it out how I can use the "previous" vector ( in it is saved every vertex  that algorithm is visiting until it succeed, but not the one that has the lowest cost) to return the right path - the one with the lower cost. As I gooogled I've seen that I need another function( that uses "previous " vector ) to compute the path . Or someone has another idea ? '

Additional information : Graph is a class with attributes - innies,outies,cost .. IterateOutbound is a function that returns a list of outbound vertices of a vertex
I read the informations from a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you basically need a few more lines of code (which you can put in a function) to compute the path to a vertex.

Something like: (in pseudo-code)

```
Stack getPath(int[] previous, int start, int end)
   int current = end
   Stack path
   path.push(current)
   while (current != start)
      current = previous[current]
      path.push(current)
   return path
```

A high-level description of this algorithm is fairly simple:

- Start from the end
- Repeatedly look at the previous element until we get to the beginning, storing the vertices as we go

Why a `Stack`? Because we're pushing the element from the end of the path, so the last element we push is the start, which would be the first element we pop if using a `Stack`.

Comment: Mate that's a great answer , with your pseudocode I fixed the problem .. just added some lines of code at the end of the function like this

int t=end;
    Path.add(t);
    while(t!=start){
        Path.add(previous[t]);
        t=previous[t];

    }
    return Path;    

(Path is a stack and add() seems to work like a push() )